# Search engine by tags

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

So, I'm new in PHP and Database and I have a problem here:

I have a table called `news` and one of its column is `tags`. This column contains 1 or more tags separated by whitespaces, like `economics politics sports`. And I have a page which will receive one or more tags as a single parameter and I have to return all rows that contains at least one of this tags.

I could explode the tags and do as many database access as necessary but I'm sure this is not the way to do it =p

`LIKE` and `IN` won't work either because the paramater may contain more than 1 tag in any order.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't how to structure that.

Have a table called news, one called tags, and one called tagsToNews.

In tagsToNews just record the news items ID and the tag ID, then do a join to get what you want. This also means a tag can be renamed without breaking everything!

Comment: Hmm, that seems like a solution, thanks =). Just another question:
I have a page to insert news as well. Is there a way to insert it and map it to a tag in the same query? Even more: If the tag dont exist, create the tag?

Comment: Not in one query, but you can always use an INSERT TRIGGER for it.

Comment: Most people do it in two queries (or however many it is), but using triggers is more robust.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I never heard of triggers before, so I'm heading for the 2 queries one. How is it? One to insert the new and other to map it? But how can you map in only one query if the new may have 2 tags? What if it is a new tag and I have to insert the tag too? I'm a little lost yet, any references? Thanks in advance =).

Answer (score 2):

**Easiest solution**

Convert your table to a MyISAM table and index the `tags` using a FULLTEXT index. From there, use the `MATCH()` function to extract a match value for the row against a query string (which may contain multiple words)

**More adaptative solution**

Drop that table and recreate it with one tag per row. You'll effectively implement a FULLTEXT array this way, as that is exactly what it is. Avoid storing data in a long string if you're planning on exploding it - usually, storing atomic portions is usually a lot more efficient as you won't have to rely on the hungry LIKE operator.